# Low Voltage Oscillation in OpAmp Circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, noise, oscillation, radar

I have a small signal from a radar sensor (in the range of 300 µV) which I want to amplify to something I can reliably measure. Fortunately the application notes of the sensor provide a recommended circuit using two inverting amplifier stages with a bandpass. The bandwidth I am interested in lies somewhere between 60-1000 Hz. The circuit works pretty well and amplifies the signal so something I can measure on the oscilloscope. However, I've noticed a strange behaviour. When the radar sensor doesn't detect any motion, the amplified output stays at 0 V for a couple for seconds and then suddenly starts oscillating randomly (looks like some sort of noise, see attached pictures) with peak voltages of about 100 mV. The same effect occurs when the input is directed directly to gnd so I am assuming that the effect is caused by my amplifier circuit. I can't seem to find out what causes the effect and was wondering if anyone could shed some light on the topic for me.

I have attached a schematic of the circuit as well as a capture of the noisy oscillating thingy. The op amp I'm using is a GS8333 and the datasheet can be found [here](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1912111437_Gainsil-GS8333-TR_C431326.pdf).

[image: amplifier schematic]
[image: noisy output]

Comment: I do not like that there is a 1 kohm resistor between the 1/2 Vcc reference and both + inputs of the opamps. There might be some coupling between the opamps through this. If you simply remove (short) that 1 k resistor then each + input is directly decoupled by the 10 uF capacitor. If you must have a 1 k resistor, give each input its own resistor. Did you also add a 10 uF supply decoupling capacitor across the supply of each opamp ?

Comment: Where did you get the schematics idea? How does a trace of the first opamp output looks like?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I would do right the opposite, I would place two 100k resistors for each non-inverting input separately in place of 1k resistor

Comment: This circuit shouldn't even work. So you have to draw a complete schematics including power supply and explain what the biasing is needed for, and how did you come with the idea that applying 2.5V bias is correct.

Comment: I was actually wondering what that 1k resistor was for. As I said, the schematic is taken directly from the application notes of the radar sensor [link](https://www.innosent.de/fileadmin/media/dokumente/Downloads/Application_Note_III_-_web.pdf).
Also, I forgot to decouple the power supply. Unfortuantely neither shorting th 1k resistor nor adding the 10uF supply cap did change anything for me here.

Comment: Your question lacks of fundamental description: complete schematics, layout, power supply, ... The output shall be biased around 2.5V while yours is AC, did you use AC coupling on the scope?  The opamp you use is very different VS app.note it has only 350Hz BW. What's the trace of 1st opamp output? And so on ...

Comment: As preference  (as stated by @Bimpelrekkie ) , If I am not wrong, the 1k resistor should be 2 (independent). One for the first op amp at left, and another for the right op amp. Another point is the figure at page 4/11 (Gain and phase plots). Very strange for the phase ?

Comment: The "anomaly" for the phase seems to be just at 30 Hz ! "GS8333 uses chopper stabilized technique to provide very low offset voltage (less than 30µV maximum) and near zero drift over temperature. " At what frequency ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I did use AC coupling so the dc offset isn't shown. As for the full schematic: that's really all there is to it. I am powering the circuit with a lab bench power supply and there's no layout yet because its all nicely built on a piece of perfboard since this is a prototype.

Comment: @Jocobes You've got a high gain bandpass for 60 Hz there in the 1st stage. (I've not analyzed what the 2nd stage does to this.) To a 1st approximation, Av is about 33 and f is so close to 60 Hz (59.94 Hz, assuming ideal values for capacitors and resistors) that it's almost surprising to me. (Try computing \$\omega_{_0}=\frac1{\sqrt{\vphantom{R^1}R_1\, R_2 \,C_1\, C_2}}\$, using your 1st stage passive values there, and then convert that result to frequency.) The 2nd stage just makes it that much worse, I fear. Are you on 60 Hz mains?? If so, I'd want to exclude 60 Hz, somehow.

Comment: @jonk I'm on 50 Hz mains actually. I'll give it a try though, thx for the suggestion!